# SVG hover not only paths but all viewbox

Tags: javascript, svg

Is it possible in this example

```css
#p1:hover {
  opacity: 0.2
}
#p1 {
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    pointer-events:all;
}
```

```html
<svg id="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 48.086 48.09">
  <path id="p1" d="M1.006 48.088c-.256 0-.498-.103-.68-.288-.217-.207-.324-.45-.324-.71L0 33.213c0-.523.426-.95.95-.95s.95.427.95.95l.003 11.62L18.905 27.84c.18-.18.418-.278.672-.278.254 0 .493.1.672.28.37.368.37.972 0 1.342L3.236 46.188h11.64c.523 0 .95.428.95.95s-.426.95-.95.95H1.007zM28.51 20.535c-.253 0-.492-.1-.67-.28-.37-.37-.37-.972 0-1.342L44.85 1.906H33.21c-.525 0-.95-.426-.95-.95s.425-.95.95-.95h13.87c.256 0 .498.103.68.29.217.208.324.45.324.71l.002 13.873c0 .523-.426.95-.95.95s-.95-.426-.95-.95l-.002-11.62-17 16.997c-.18.18-.42.278-.673.278zM19.58 20.525c-.253 0-.492-.1-.67-.28L1.9 3.236 1.9 14.876c0 .525-.426.95-.95.95S0 15.4 0 14.876l.002-13.87c0-.257.104-.5.29-.68C.5.107.743 0 1.003 0L14.876 0c.524 0 .95.426.95.95s-.426.95-.95.95l-11.62.002 16.997 17c.37.372.37.975 0 1.345-.18.18-.42.278-.672.278zM33.21 48.086c-.524 0-.95-.427-.95-.95 0-.254.098-.492.277-.672.18-.18.418-.277.672-.278l11.62-.003L27.833 29.18c-.37-.37-.37-.973 0-1.343.18-.18.418-.278.67-.278.255 0 .494.098.673.277L46.183 44.85V33.207c0-.523.426-.95.95-.95s.95.427.95.95v13.87c0 .26-.105.5-.293.683-.207.216-.45.322-.71.322l-13.87.004z"/>
</svg>
```

to initiate hover action not only when pointer is over paths but when it's generally over the icon even between the paths? It's very important that I don't add any extra markup. HTML section needs to remain as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your `:hover` to the SVG (`#icon`) element as you would if working with any other HTML structure:

```css
#icon:hover #p1 {
  opacity: 0.2
}
#p1 {
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    pointer-events:all;
}
```

```html
<svg id="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 48.086 48.09">
  <path id="p1" d="M1.006 48.088c-.256 0-.498-.103-.68-.288-.217-.207-.324-.45-.324-.71L0 33.213c0-.523.426-.95.95-.95s.95.427.95.95l.003 11.62L18.905 27.84c.18-.18.418-.278.672-.278.254 0 .493.1.672.28.37.368.37.972 0 1.342L3.236 46.188h11.64c.523 0 .95.428.95.95s-.426.95-.95.95H1.007zM28.51 20.535c-.253 0-.492-.1-.67-.28-.37-.37-.37-.972 0-1.342L44.85 1.906H33.21c-.525 0-.95-.426-.95-.95s.425-.95.95-.95h13.87c.256 0 .498.103.68.29.217.208.324.45.324.71l.002 13.873c0 .523-.426.95-.95.95s-.95-.426-.95-.95l-.002-11.62-17 16.997c-.18.18-.42.278-.673.278zM19.58 20.525c-.253 0-.492-.1-.67-.28L1.9 3.236 1.9 14.876c0 .525-.426.95-.95.95S0 15.4 0 14.876l.002-13.87c0-.257.104-.5.29-.68C.5.107.743 0 1.003 0L14.876 0c.524 0 .95.426.95.95s-.426.95-.95.95l-11.62.002 16.997 17c.37.372.37.975 0 1.345-.18.18-.42.278-.672.278zM33.21 48.086c-.524 0-.95-.427-.95-.95 0-.254.098-.492.277-.672.18-.18.418-.277.672-.278l11.62-.003L27.833 29.18c-.37-.37-.37-.973 0-1.343.18-.18.418-.278.67-.278.255 0 .494.098.673.277L46.183 44.85V33.207c0-.523.426-.95.95-.95s.95.427.95.95v13.87c0 .26-.105.5-.293.683-.207.216-.45.322-.71.322l-13.87.004z"/>
</svg>
```

Because you are effecting the whole element, the `#p` selector is not needed, so you could simplify a little further:

```css
#icon:hover {
  opacity: 0.2
}
#p1 {
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    pointer-events:all;
}
```

```html
<svg id="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 48.086 48.09">
  <path id="p1" d="M1.006 48.088c-.256 0-.498-.103-.68-.288-.217-.207-.324-.45-.324-.71L0 33.213c0-.523.426-.95.95-.95s.95.427.95.95l.003 11.62L18.905 27.84c.18-.18.418-.278.672-.278.254 0 .493.1.672.28.37.368.37.972 0 1.342L3.236 46.188h11.64c.523 0 .95.428.95.95s-.426.95-.95.95H1.007zM28.51 20.535c-.253 0-.492-.1-.67-.28-.37-.37-.37-.972 0-1.342L44.85 1.906H33.21c-.525 0-.95-.426-.95-.95s.425-.95.95-.95h13.87c.256 0 .498.103.68.29.217.208.324.45.324.71l.002 13.873c0 .523-.426.95-.95.95s-.95-.426-.95-.95l-.002-11.62-17 16.997c-.18.18-.42.278-.673.278zM19.58 20.525c-.253 0-.492-.1-.67-.28L1.9 3.236 1.9 14.876c0 .525-.426.95-.95.95S0 15.4 0 14.876l.002-13.87c0-.257.104-.5.29-.68C.5.107.743 0 1.003 0L14.876 0c.524 0 .95.426.95.95s-.426.95-.95.95l-11.62.002 16.997 17c.37.372.37.975 0 1.345-.18.18-.42.278-.672.278zM33.21 48.086c-.524 0-.95-.427-.95-.95 0-.254.098-.492.277-.672.18-.18.418-.277.672-.278l11.62-.003L27.833 29.18c-.37-.37-.37-.973 0-1.343.18-.18.418-.278.67-.278.255 0 .494.098.673.277L46.183 44.85V33.207c0-.523.426-.95.95-.95s.95.427.95.95v13.87c0 .26-.105.5-.293.683-.207.216-.45.322-.71.322l-13.87.004z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is easier than I thought in pure SVG:) However, I forgot to mention that I'm using Snap.svg and load this icon from external file. Could you perhaps tell me why it doesn't work here? [link](http://przemoo83.esy.es/snap/)

Comment: Hmmm, not sure to be honest. The outer SVG (`#product-main`) seems to be preventing it working as expected. I don't know why that would be. I think you should open another question that shows the issue as it seems to be unrelated to your initial problem.

Comment: Yeah you probably right. The answer you provided here is still useful to me. Thanks!

Comment: Post a link here if you open a new question and I will help if I find anything useful.